# How to set time lapse between songs on playlist in Windows Media Player?

Tags: windows-10, windows-media-player

How do you create a specific time lapse between songs in a Windows Media Player playlist on Windows 10?

Comment: I have created a 16 second silent track between my music. Works well until windows does an update. Windows change the mp3 settings to mp4 and ignores my pause. I have to make a new playlist after each update.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that you wish to have a delay between the end of one song and the beginning of the next.

This [forum thread](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/119595-pause-between-songs-in-windows-media-player/) talks about exactly that. The conclusion was that while WMP doesn't support this feature, you may get an acceptable simulation by setting a long crossfade time. If this is insufficient for your needs, you'll need to use a different player, such as [Winamp](http://www.winamp.com/), which supports the feature you require.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool (like a microphone recording tool) to create a file
that contains *n* seconds of silence. 
(Or you can probably download pre-made files like that from the Internet.)
Then add that file to your playlist, between songs.